# how do i get last result in group by MySQL query (not the first)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+--+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|ID| lt_user           | lt_time_stamp       | lt_activity_operation |
+--+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|1 | External Sales    | 2013-02-15 15:17:34 | login                 |
|2 | External Sales    | 2013-03-20 16:25:09 | login                 |
|3 | Internal Sales    | 2013-07-29 13:09:22 | login                 |
|4 | Internal Sales    | 2013-08-01 11:06:11 | login                 |
|5 | Internal sales    | 2013-08-02 10:06:59 | login                 |
|6 | internal sales    | 2013-08-02 10:21:38 | login                 |
|7 | internal sales    | 2013-08-07 16:13:01 | login                 |
|8 | Internal Sales    | 2013-08-12 10:51:16 | login                 |
+--+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

I'm trying to retrieve the last instance (Time stamp) of each user once.

What i need is:

```
+--+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|ID| lt_user           | lt_time_stamp       | lt_activity_operation |
+--+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|2 | External Sales    | 2013-03-20 16:25:09 | login                 |
|8 | Internal Sales    | 2013-08-12 10:51:16 | login                 |
+--+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

What I'm getting is:

```
+--+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|ID| lt_user           | lt_time_stamp       | lt_activity_operation |
+--+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|3 | Internal Sales    | 2013-07-29 13:09:22 | login                 |
|1 | External Sales    | 2013-02-15 15:17:34 | login                 |
+--+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

My Query is:

```
SELECT lt_user, lt_time_stamp, lt_activity_operation
  FROM log_table
 GROUP BY lt_user
 ORDER BY lt_time_stamp DESC;
```

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't do what you think'say it does. It returns a *random* time stamp per user. Read about selecting columns that do & don't appear in group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Like this

`SELECT lt_user, MAX(lt_time_stamp), lt_activity_operation 
FROM log_table 
GROUP BY lt_user, lt_activity_operation 
ORDER BY lt_time_stamp DESC;`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `MAX()`:

```
SELECT lt_user, MAX(lt_time_stamp), lt_activity_operation 
FROM log_table GROUP BY lt_user, lt_activity_operation;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cc68/2)

Comment: The OP is grouping by `lt_user`, not `lt_user, lt_activity_operation`

Answer (score 0):

limit version:

```
SELECT lt_user, lt_time_stamp, lt_activity_operation 
FROM log_table GROUP BY lt_user, lt_activity_operation 
ORDER BY lt_time_stamp DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to get the last row is to do the aggregation to get the `max()` value and then join back to the original data:

```
select lt.*
from (SELECT lt_user, max(lt_time_stamp) as maxts
      FROM log_table
      GROUP BY lt_user 
     ) ltsum join
     log_table lt
     on ltsum.lt_user = lt.user and ltsum.maxts = lt.lt_time_stamp;
```

In this case, you only need to get the last activity.  You can also do it with this trick:

```
SELECT lt_user, max(lt_time_stamp) as maxts,
       substring_index(group_concat(lt_activity_operation order by lt_time_stamp desc), ',', 1
                      ) as last_activity
FROM log_table
GROUP BY lt_user;
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `GROUP BY` command, you need to tell SQL which one of all the records selected should be shown, as it takes all of them and groups them in one single resulting record per grouped records. Because of this, you need to choose the `MAX()` or any other specific function or parameter for it (in your case, the timestamp).

```
    SELECT lt_user, MAX(lt_time_stamp), lt_activity_operation
      FROM log_table
     GROUP BY lt_user
     ORDER BY lt_time_stamp DESC;
```

`lt_activity_operation` column doesn't need a function if it's all the same (login in your db), but might need to be chosen the same way as    lt_time_stamp     if it came to it.